# Accessing R through a cloud platform

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, rstudio-server

I was wondering if anyone had success accessing R and R studio through a cloud platform like OneDrive. Because once my project started compiling on one of my drives on my computer, the drive started filling up due to like 5-6 on going projects and I do need access to them and therefore I don't have the capacity to delete them either. It's troublesome to save all the files I do to a cloud too. Currently I have a 256 SSD with STATA, SPSS and MortPak in addition to R. Appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: MS OneDrive is less a platform (for running things) than a file-hosting (and synchronization) service. R needs to be run locally, there are numerous problems (mostly on Windows) with R running on mounted network shares (even just compiling packages on a network share can have issues on Windows). If you're in a pinch, consider leasing a VM (e.g., DigitalOcean, not an endorsement) and learn how to install `rstudio-server` on it. My guess is that you can also figure out how to install the others on it, too.

Comment: I suspect, though, that this question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow, for several possible reasons such as being related to *"general computing hardware and software"*. It might be more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com); if you get no responses here (or it is closed), consider going there. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your responses! Will try VM out.